# Ehcache calling loadAll cacheloaderwriter with single item iterable

Tags: ehcache

I am using Ehcache 3.1.1 on heap store.

```
cache = cacheManager.createCache(name,
            CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(key, value, ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(entries))
                    .withLoaderWriter(loader)
                    .build()
);
```

I have a CacheLoaderWriter which supports loadAll. 
When making calls to getAll on the cache, misses route through to the loader, but call loadAll multiple times with single item iterators.

I believe this may be an issue in OnHeapStore bulkComputeIfAbsent

Please advise if I am missing a configuration to enable batching via loadAll.
I was unable to find this reported as a bug.

EDIT: I don't feel like I explained it well originally. So getAll is called with a key set size of 2, loadAll is called twice in that situation with the keyset being size of 1 each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did nothing wrong in your configuration - please open an issue against [Ehcache3](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3)